# Jquery Fancybox height / scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i am using fancybox for displaying certain pages on my website.
my problem is that i have no idea how i can make it with a fixed height and to scroll down to view more content if necessary (if the content flows down more than the specific height parameter of the fancybox)

here are my parameters in the page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox_link").fancybox({
    'width'             : 680,
    'height'            : 550,
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'autoDimensions'    : false,
    'scrolling'         : 'no',
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
</script>
```

what should i do to make the content flow with a scroll bar for the height?
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit :** Is it the "Scrolling : 'yes'" parameter that doesn't work ?

Otherwise, I think, you can to edit/overwrite the Fancybox CSS :

```
#fancybox-content {
    height: 680px;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Or something like this. I've do that for a previous project, but don't have the code under the hand to give you the exact syntax.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your edit because in on top. That would be the correct answer ... the css rules in this case are misleading.

Comment: Yes... I used the CSS with a previous version of Fancybox, if I remember correctly.

Comment: still in this scenario you don't need to mess with the fancybox css file

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to set the option

```
'scrolling' : 'yes',
```

That will create scroll bars inside fancybox so you can browse long content.

Comment: @Akarun got it first, just ignore his comments about the css

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

'autoSize'          : false